# Implementing k-means algorithm correctly

Tags: cluster-analysis, matlab, algorithm, k-means

I've just started to learn to code and had a go at writing the standard k-means algorithm. I tried my implementation on a data set generated with three different Gaussians and it seems to work well. However I tried it on the iris data set and every now and then (around third of the time) my function returns only two sets, in other words it returns only two clusters.

I had a peek at the code for the local MATLAB kmeans function but I ended up getting lost due to my lack of coding knowledge. I would really appreciate any help!

```
function [R,C,P,it] = mykmeans(X,K)
% X -- data matrix
% K -- number of clusters
% C -- partition sets
% P -- matrix of prototypes
% R -- binary indicator matrix: R(i,j) specifies whether the ith data is
% classified into jth cluster
% it -- number of iterations until convergence

% N points with M dimensions
[N,M] = size(X) ;

%% Initialisation

% At this step we randomly partition the data matrix into K equally sized
% matrices and compute the centre of each of these matrices.
% I -- randomised index vector
% v -- number of data points assigned to each cluster
% U -- randomly partitioned matrices

v = N/K ;
C = cell(K,1) ;
U = cell(K,1) ;
I = randperm(N) ;
oldR = zeros(N,K) ;

% C{1} = X(I(1:v),:) ;
% U{1} = mean(X(I(1:v),:)) ;
for k=1:K
    C{k} = X(I(1+v*(k-1):k*v),:) ;
    U{k} = mean(C{k}) ;
end

P = cell2mat(U) ;

converged = 0 ;
it = 0 ;
while converged ~= 1

    %% Assignment step

    % Each element of D{n} contains squared euclidean distance of nth data 
    % point from the kth prototype
    D = cell(N,1) ;
    R = zeros(N,K) ;
    for n=1:N
        D{n} = sum((repmat(X(n,:),K,1) - P).^2,2) ;
        [~,k] = min(D{n}) ;
        R(n,k) = 1 ; 
    end

    %% Update step

    C = cell(K,1) ; % reset C
    for k=1:K
        for n=1:N
            P(k,:) = R(n,k)*X(n,:) + P(k,:) ; % compute numerator of mean vector
            if R(n,k) == 1
                C{k} = [C{k};X(n,:)] ;
            end
        end
    end

    P = P ./ (sum(R)') ; % divide by denominator of mean vectors to get prototypes

%% Check for convergence

    if sum(sum(R == oldR))==N*K || it == 100 % convergence criteria
        converged = 1 ;
    else
        oldR = R ;
        it = it+1 ;
    end
end %while
```

Comment: This is off topic for the CV site.  I recommend migrating to StackOverflow.

Comment: This is off-topic, nobody wants to debug the code here.

Comment: Actually, I think the underlying issue might not be programming-related, but statistical (in the sense that similar behaviour can happen with correct implementation of k-means). Let's hold off on calling for migration until it's clear it's actually a programming issue.

Comment: Posting code is not generally off-topic, sometimes it is just one of the most efficient way to present an issue. However the poster could have emphasized the wrong result and specifically asked for why this result occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys I will make sure not to make the same mistake next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem indeed seems not a coding problem but an issue of understanding k-means.

In fact during k-means, clusters can become empty. You will need to account in your code for this, as otherwise the number of clusters in your result can be smaller than k.

A possible solutions could be:

- assigning a random data point as the new cluster center for the empty cluster
- choosing the point most far from the biggest cluster as the new cluster center for the empty cluster

The general approach therefore goes such as:

1. Initialize k cluster centers (for example: random)
2. Assign all data points to the closest cluster center
3. Recompute the cluster centers based on the assignment
4. Check for empty clusters
5. Repeat steps 2 - 4 until convergence (== cluster centers did not change in the last iteration)

A great illustration of the issue of empty clusters can be found [here](http://user.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~tcan/ceng465_f1314/Schedule/KMeansEmpty.html).

Comment: Choosing the point most far from the largest cluster seems to have fixed the issue. Cheers!

Comment: Nikolas, +1. Can you say more about the options to fix the empty cluster problem - I mean, first of all, which of the two options you mention is "better" or is more widely used (if you are aware, of course).

Comment: P.S. Some programs do this: if an empty cluster(s) emerges, K is lessened to the number of nonempty ones, and the iterations go on with that reduced number of clusters.

Comment: Just to drag in some collected related links from CrossValidated, for the audience: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/152333/3277; http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/89926/3277; http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/125655/3277; http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13744/3277;

Comment: I do not consider reducing the number of K during the runtime a good option. Rather directly choose a good k (domain knowledge) or if no domain knowledge is present, use an algorithm which does not require k as input such as DBSCAN.

Comment: Or you can use all relevant k's and evaluate the result regarding inter-cluster and intra-cluster distance.

Comment: `choosing the point most far from the biggest cluster` Biggest by populatedness of biggest physically (variance)?

Comment: Good question. Intuition says populatedness, yet a theoretic explanation would be nice. I dont have one now.